# php include returns 1 as output with other outputs

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, include

I have this code

```
$return = include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/apex.php' );

$html .= $return;
```

I using the above code to get a php for from a plugin from theme dir. but it returns 1 with the other wanted outputs. how to solve this

I have seen the other question on stackoverflow but those hasn't work

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not WordPress-specific, and does therefore not belong in WordPress.StackExchange. As it's so easy to answer, however...

`include` is not a function, but it does return whatever you put in "return" inside the file that's included. You can use an [output buffer](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to "catch" all output:

```
ob_start();
include TEMPLATEPATH . '/apex.php';
$html .= ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: You should flag off topic questions than rather answering them.

Comment: @engelen thanks this works. and sorry won't repeat this, i will make sure i post it on the right place. again thanks

Comment: @PieterGoosen Nah. Didn't feel like not answering.

Comment: `include` returns whatever the included file returns.

Comment: Good point @toscho, my bad, I've fixed my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but the included file must `return` a value. If you want to combine the value with a string it should be a scalar (integer, float, string or boolean).

Let’s say, `apex.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

return 'Hello!';
```

Now you can assign the `include` to a variable:

```
$return = include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/apex.php' );
```

This works with `include_once`, `require`, and `require_once` too.

But if the file does not return a value, you have to use [output buffering](https://www.php.net//manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).